# In NodeJS, how to use the same object in different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

there are three files :

- a.js
- b.js
- token.js

**I need to use the same token in `a.js` and `b.js`, How do I achieve that?** for example, set token in `a.js` and get token in `b.js`

I am using a singleton but it does not work :(

**token.js**

```
class Token {
  private static instance: Token

  private _hash = 'default-hash'

  private constructor() {

  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (!Token.instance) {
      Token.instance = new Token()
    }
    return Token.instance
  }

  //setter and getter for _hash

}

export default Token
```

Comment: Are you using two node processes?

Comment: @JosuGoñi I just start one `next.js` process, I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

The module.exports or exports is a special object which is included in every JS file in the Node.js application by default. module is a variable that represents current module and exports is an object that will be exposed as a module. So, whatever you assign to module.exports or exports, will be exposed as a module.

**Examples: Export Literals**

File: message.js

```
module.exports = 'Hello world';
```

Now, import this message module and use it as shown below.

File: app.js

```
var msg = require('./messages.js');
console.log(msg);
```

**Example: Export Object**

message.js

```
exports.SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';
//or
module.exports.SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';
```

In the above example, we have attached a property "SimpleMessage" to the exports object. Now, import and use this module as shown below.

app.js

```
var msg = require('./messages.js');
console.log(msg.SimpleMessage);
```

**Example: Export Function**

You can attach an anonymous function to exports object as shown below.

log.js

```
module.exports = function (msg) { 
    console.log(msg);
};
```

Now, you can use the above module as below.

app.js

```
var msg = require('./log.js');
msg('Hello World');
```